# How to replace all special characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, ascii, special-characters

I want to replace all special character in ASCII-%.
Like this list:

```
? -> %3F
! -> %21
...
```

Till now i have replaced 2 special characters. But i doesnt know a simple method to replace all special characters.

This is my code:

```
var replacer1 = new RegExp("\\?", "g");
var replacer2 = new RegExp("/", "g");
var q = ((query).replace(replacer1, "%3F")).replace(replacer2, "%2F");
```

Comment: Have a look at [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: only encodeURIComponent will encode the ? character. Neither will encode the ! character.

Comment: You can use `encodeURI` to encode for most of your characters; for rest of them, you can run a regex match!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what your trying to do is url encode your special characters just use the functions:

- encodeURIComponent
- encodeURI

depending on whether you are encoding an entire url or just a component. e.g.

```
encodeURIComponent("as686sa8d6sa8787^%^%$^£$%£$%");
//Output: "as686sa8d6sa8787%5E%25%5E%25%24%5E%C2%A3%24%25%C2%A3%24%25"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although deprecated, the `escape('myString');` method will do the job and cater for both ? and ! symbols